# Name of JQuery technique used on this site

Tags: jquery

What is the effect or jquery plugin used to create the on hover video effect used on this site?
http://www.iwc.com/it/collezione/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hi
2. It's not Jquery, it's Flash
3. Your question is not Wordpress related